# Missing $ in overleaf

Tags: math-mode, errors

So Hello I again,

I asked a question a few minutes ago and got great answers in a few minutes. Hence, I was encouraged to ask more. Thank you for your help everyone.

So I am getting missing $ inserted error for this code. Where am I missing a $?

```
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0-56\[^{\circ }\] (85\% of the population)\\ 0-27\[^{\circ }
\] (15\% of the population)\end{tabular} & 5-73\[^{\circ }\] & 0-100\[^{\circ }\]   & 0-105\[^{\circ }
\]   & 0-85\[^{\circ }\]  \\ \hline
\end{tabular} \label{tablo}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I am trying to generate a small table basically.

Also I have a bunch of equations that I need to convert to Latex code. I tried MathType which worked great for most but still seems to output erroneous code. Do you guys have any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a fully and compilable `MWE`

Comment: please always provide a full example (as in Ulrike's answer) so people can run it and see the problem. (But the error is you can not use display math `\[...\]` in a one-line context like a tabular `c` column,

Comment: I figured I did not put a full `MWE` after submitting the answer question but I then I said maybe you guys won't need the whole thing (at least for this problem). Anyway, I promise I will do my best next time but I really really appreciate your help guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should better use siunitx to type your input:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase = --, range-units=single}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
\SIrange{0}{56}{\degree} (\SI{85}{\percent} of the population)\\
\SIrange{0}{27}{\degree} (\SI{15}{\percent} of the population)\\
\hline
\end{tabular} \label{tablo}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many formatting errors are there in the `MWE`, `\[...\]` code should use for unnumbered display math, `$...$` is for inline math, refer the modified `MWE` below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
0-56$^{\circ }$ (85\% of the population)\\ 
0-27$^{\circ }$ (15\% of the population)\\
5-73$^{\circ }$ \\
 0-100$^{\circ }$\\
0-105$^{\circ }$\\
0-85$^{\circ }$  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular} \label{tablo}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Also you didn't provide complete `MWE`, hence I've used standard `book` class file...